# Primefaces 4 + Spring: datatable show empty message while datamodel List has values

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to upgrade my application to latest versions of the jars, in particular I have moved from:

JSF 2.1.12 -->> 2.2.1

Spring webflow 2.3.1 -->> 2.4.0

Primefaces 3.4.1 -->> 4.0

Spring core 3.2.0.M1

The application run fine but every p:datatable in the system shows as empty, with the default message "No records found.", while the datamodel List I pass as value are not empty. Here's a simple example:

The flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
    parent="GlobalMenu_subflows">

    <persistence-context  />

     <view-state id="test" view="../views/test.xhtml">
        <on-entry>
            <evaluate expression="textManager.getAllTexts(brandNames)" result="viewScope.texts" result-type="dataModel"/>
            <set value="'fixed'" name="viewScope.contentGroup"/>
        </on-entry>

     </view-state>

</flow>
```

Where textManager.getAllTexts returns a list of TranslatedText. The converter for the result-type, dataModel, is the deafult one, I didn't overwrite it.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public List<TranslatedText> getAllTexts(String brandNames)
{
    return textDao.findAllTranslatedTextByBrandNames(brandNames);
}
```

and the pages is:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:sv="http://www.synaptic.com/sb"
                xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:sf="http://www.springframework.org/tags/faces"
                template="/WEB-INF/layouts/standard.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

        <div>

            <h:form id="viewForm" >
                <h:panelGroup id="textFormPanel" name="textFormPanel">
                    <sv:csrfHidden />
                    <p:dataTable id="viewTable" 
                                 name="viewTable" 
                                 var="text" 
                                 rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
                                 value="${texts}" 
                                 paginator="true" 
                                 rows="10"  
                                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  

                                 paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                                 styleClass="adminDataTable"
                                 rowKey="#{text.id}">

                        <p:column filterBy="#{text.key}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Key" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="${text.key}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Component" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="${text.component}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Type" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="${text.type}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>

        </div>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Everything used to work before the migration, and I get no errors at all in the console. I'm using eclipse for testing and in debug I'm sure the list of TranslatedText is full (about 2000 rows).

I checked all the migration guides but could not find any reference that could produce this error. I suspect it has something to do with the dataModel. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Mattia

**#######** **EDIT** **#########**

I'm trying all possible combinations and I narrowed down the cause.

As a start is not a Primefaces problem for sure as also JSF h:dataTable, nor the c:forEach, works. But I can't switch back to a previous webflow as anything before 2.4 fails miserably before reaching the page.

The error comes indeed from the webflow (or from the interaction of JSF and webflow) because if I move the OneSelectionTrackingListDataModel object inside a managed bean instead of using the webflow flowScope everything works fine.

```
@Component("testFlowObject")
public class TestFlowObject {

    public OneSelectionTrackingListDataModel model;

    public OneSelectionTrackingListDataModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(OneSelectionTrackingListDataModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

}

<view-state id="test" view="../views/test.xhtml">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="textManager.getAllTexts(brandNames)" result="flowScope.texts" result-type="dataModel"/>
        <evaluate expression="testFlowObject.setModel(texts)"/>
        <set value="'fixed'" name="viewScope.contentGroup"/>
    </on-entry>

</view-state>
```

Now I could refactor the whole system to work like this, if it's a better practice. But I would like to understand what's going on and try to fix the cause of the error. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Simply forget about using jsf combined with Spring view frameworks. It'll carry you on problems.

Comment: It generally works fine apart from this new inexplicable (by me) error on the new version. The application is huge and required years of development, changing environment is not an option.